# How to detect if an arrow hit a red wool block in 1.14?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to test if an arrow hit a red wool block in a Minecraft 1.14. I'm using the following command:

`execute if entity @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:arrow"},inTile:{minecraft:red_wool},inData:0b}] run say hi`

However, it does not work for me. What can I change to get this command to work correctly?

Comment: I don't think you need the `inData` tag, and I have a feeling you'll need the `tag` tag, but I haven't looked at the NBT data structure for arrows in order to tell you exactly what's wrong with the command.

Comment: Would a detector facing the wool block be able to pick up the update? This could power your command block, making the command a bit simpler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command isn't working because you are conflating item entities and arrow entities. The selector `@e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:arrow"}}]` matches item entities containing arrows (when you drag an arrow out of your inventory and put it on the ground), not arrow entites (what happens when you shoot an arrow). Item entities don't have a `inTile` tag, so the command can never match anything.

---

Additionally, `inTile` is for an old version of Minecraft, and the correct NBT tag is `inBlockState`.

---

The following command (untested) should properly detect arrows in red wool.

```
execute if entity @e[type=arrow,nbt={inBlockState:{Name:"minecraft:red_wool"}}] run say hi
```